# How to handle large strings in swift?

Tags: swift, string, performance

I've this code and its taking a lot of time to execute in swift?
**Each iteration takes 1 second to execute, Why?**

*CPU Percentage while executing that loop is 97-98% and energy impact is High*

Here is the Code

```
     var braces:Int = 1;
     var i:Int = startIndex;
     let jsFileChars = Array(javascriptFile);
      while(i < javascriptFile.count){   //count:1240265        
         if (braces == 0) {
              break;
         }                            
        if (jsFileChars[i] == "{"){     
             braces = braces+1;
         }else if (jsFileChars[i] == "}"){
              braces = braces-1;
         }
             i = i+1;
   }
```

This loop is iterated on a very slow pace, why?

Comment: Because 1.2 million iterations are a lot(?). Also, can you define 'a lot of time'? What would be an acceptable amount of time?

Comment: I've put a log in the project to print the braces, I donno why that log prints for every second?

Comment: @MartinR Now updated it, Please look to it and its Xcode project and its  taking very bad time of execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loop is slow because determining the `count` of a Swift *string* is a
O(N) operation, where N is the number of characters in the string.
See also [Counting Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID297) in “The Swift Programming Language”:

> NOTE
>
> Extended grapheme clusters can be composed of multiple Unicode scalars. This means that different characters—and different representations of the same character—can require different amounts of memory to store. Because of this, characters in Swift don’t each take up the same amount of memory within a string’s representation. As a result, the number of characters in a string can’t be calculated without iterating through the string to determine its extended grapheme cluster boundaries. ...

Replacing `javascriptFile.count` by `jsFileChars.count` should already
improve the performance, because the length of an array is determined in
constant time.

Even better iterate over the characters directly, without creating an
array at all:

```
var braces = 1
for char in javascriptFile {
    if char == "{" {
        braces += 1
    } else if char == "}" {
        braces -= 1
    }
}
```

Iterating over the UTF-16 view is even faster, because that
is what Swift strings (currently) use as internal storage:

```
let openingBrace = "{".utf16.first!
let closingBrace = "}".utf16.first!

var braces = 1
for char in javascriptFile.utf16 {
    if char == openingBrace {
        braces += 1
    } else if char == closingBrace {
        braces -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Martin That's awesome. You are genius.

Answer (score 2):

When you're thinking of iterating over a collection in Swift (and a String is a collection of characters), it's sometimes faster to use [`reduce()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894473-reduce) instead. You can implement your brace counter using `reduce()` like this:

```
let braces = javascriptFile.reduce(0, { count, char in
    switch char {
    case "{": return count + 1
    case "}": return count - 1
    default: return count
    }
})
```

I don't know if that'll actually be faster than using a `for` loop in your case, but might be worth a try. If nothing else, the intent is very clear when written this way.

Comment: I like that it evaluates to a *constant.* – But I am fairly sure that reduce() always processes the elements sequentially and not in parallel. In my simple test there was no significant difference in timing between reduce and a for-loop.

Comment: @MartinR Thinking about it, I'm sure you're right -- the closure that `reduce()` takes doesn't have a way to combine results from several `reduce()` operations -- `reduce()` is often used to combine the results from several `map()` operations into a single result. Even so, I like the `reduce()` option here if only because it makes the intent very clear. I suppose you could divide the string and use `map()` to count braces in each substring, and then `reduce()` the result to combine.

Comment: The only thing that is not possible with `reduce()` is the "early return", like the  `if (braces == 0) { break }` in the question.